Make Visual Studio Code open projects in a new window unless window is empty
I have this issue which is always bothering me about Visual Studio Code, I was wondering if there is a way around it:
I want it to open projects in a new window unless the current window is empty, then just open the project in the current window.
I know I can make it open projects in a new window by default by setting
"window.openFoldersInNewWindow": "on"


Which is how I generally want it to behave, like if I already have a project open, I want any new project I'm opening to go into a new window.
However when I first start vscode, or if I hit "New Window", I get an empty window, and when I open a project from this empty window it opens another window with the project in it which makes no sense because it just leaves a useless empty window I have to manually close every time.
Is there a way to change this behaviour? Am I misunderstanding the intended workflow?

what methods do you use to open a new window? if you only ever use keybindings, as a guess, you can probably achieve this with when clauses.

I mostly use workbench.action.openRecent (^+R Hotkey).
I did think I would maybe just write an extension to replace the menu that does this, but I wish there was an easier way, I was also just curious how other people handle it since it makes no sense to me to have this behavior that just leaves behind empty windows
